# can I write in this format xml file?

Tags: xml

I want to write an xml file

the stander to write is :

```
<expression>
<primary   text="More_Informations" >

</primary>
</expression>
```

I ask if I can write the xml file in this format :

```
<expression
<primary
text=  "His_Department_Date" />/>
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't.

Tags cannot appear inside other tags. Only attributes may go there.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not classed as "well-formed" so will not work and technically is not XML due to not being "well-formed".

Have a read through [Checking XML Well-Formedness](https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/19.0/ug-editorEclipse/topics/checking-xml-well-formedness.html), it may help you understand how you need to structure the markup.